# Game strategy using minimax on TicTacToe?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

Suppose there are 4 possible moves and all are guaranteed for player O to lose. There is no chance of drawing or a win. X will eventually always win.

So amongst those 4 moves, is it better to choose the move that would end the game for O quickly or later after few moves?

If I don't bother with coming up with a strategy and just select a move randomly then off course less memory will be used.

Note: I am not always starting from a blank board and testing my solutions on random game states. Also, both players are computer and thus playing a perfect game.

Answer (score 1):

If the human plays X, then it's better to choose the move that would end the game for O later after few moves, in case the human player makes a mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, both players are computers and thus playing a perfect game.

Comment: What's your goal in having two computers play against each other?

Comment: ok then it is just a trade-off you have to make between CPU and RAM costs.

Comment: @NeilDA If both players play perfectly, it will result in a tie every time.

Comment: Yes it would, but from a blank board. If I start the game from a different state where X's and O's are already placed, then it won't.

Comment: (Also it depends if you use the standard 3x3 tic-tac-toe or some variations)